# Is fastlane still needed with VS Appcenter?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

Like the title says. I am planning to use Visual Studio AppCenter. Where does fastlane fit in there? As I am seeing it, fastlane becomes redunant when switching over to VSAC?
Or am I missing the bigger picture here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Visual Studio App Center certainly does a lot of the things fastlane does, but it depends fully on your individual use case if you can fully *replace* fastlane with App Center.

A major conceptual difference is that App Center is a **hosted software as a service** that you can use to do common things (build, test, publish) with your app. Fastlane on the other hand is a **local tool (that can also be used in a server environment)** that does whatever you want with your app. If there is no built-in [action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions) or [plugin](https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/using-plugins/) for your specific and custom use case, you can just write one yourself and add the functionality.

Fastlane is actually [one of the installed tools on the App Center build servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/software), so you don't even have to decide if you want to use one or the other - you can still use fastlane *with* App Center.

(App Center also uses fastlane behind the scenes itself for features like [App Store and TestFlight Distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/apple) for example)

Comment: Cool! Then my thought process seems correct. For anyone interested I also found this fastlane plugin https://github.com/microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter

Comment: do AppCenter users need that plugin >?